# Using TextBox with Type=datetime , in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, visual-studio-2010

I have textbox like that (VS 2010):

```
<asp:TextBox type="date" ID="rSLA" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
```

and it's working fine, but when I change the type to : datetime (cause I need date and hour)  , the datepicker not working.
why?

Thank you.

Comment: This is new html5 date types. 
you can read about it here:
http://www.wufoo.com/html5/types/4-date.html

Comment: adding TextMode="DateTimeLocal" instead of type="date" fixed my problem in this case and it gave me a datepicker

Answer (score 4):

Which browser are you using? I notice [on there](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_input_types.asp) that for Chrome, `datetime` is unsupported but `datetime-local` is, maybe that solves your problem.

Comment: thanks, this fixed my problem, but on my IDE (VS2013) its DateTimeLocal instead of datetime-local!

Answer (score 0):

setting `type="datetime"` for textbox it Doesn't Mean that it will show calender for You.
You can Use Calender from Ajax

in front of TextBox

```
<asp:TextBox ID="rSLA" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" Width="150px" 
                DayNameFormat="Shortest"  Height="25px" /> 
            </asp:Calendar>
```

Refer this
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19991/DatePicker-in-ASP-NET-and-AJAX-Control-Toolkit

Comment: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/mobile/exploring-html5s-new-datetime-input-types-for-your-web-apps.html#fbid=6tfvRbf2xKt

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to use HTML5 datetime input type, it's good to check on what browsers support it first. According to [this](http://caniuse.com/input-datetime), it only appears a few mobile browsers are supported. So instead you should use a 3rd party Datepicker. There's a [built-in one](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/control_calendar.asp) that doesn't work very well, there's one in the [Ajax Control Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Calendar/Calendar.aspx) that works well, [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) has one (that's my personal pref) or you can Google for one.