# How can I pull back DateTime and store in textbox with type=date in C# asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, time

I am new to C#

I am trying to populate this text box with a value in my backcode, however I am struggling to get it showing. When I load the page, it just has a default `'dd/MM/yyyy'` displaying rather than the date in my database. It has to be editable that is why the textbox is type Date.

Front Code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="DoB" runat="server" Type="Date" placeholder="DoB:" 
      Style="float: left; width: inherit;"></asp:TextBox>
```

BackCode:

```
        string dob = rdr["DOB"].ToString();
        DoB.Text = dob.ToString();`
```

The Date is: `23/03/2018 12:00:00 AM`

Anyone know what is going wrong here? Any help would be great. Thanks in advance!

Comment: you should really use datetime type in your DB

Comment: What is the type of the DOB column in your database table?

Comment: Assuming you are getting a DateTime back - the ToString() method will show the time - check out the ToShortDateString method or ToString with formatting parameter methods : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime_methods(v=vs.110).aspx  - just as an aside you don't need to use dob.ToString() when assigning to DoB.Text - dob is already a string.

Comment: The DB type is DateTime. I have removed the ToString() method from where I am assigning the text but no joy yet..

Comment: Have to tried using rdr["DOB"].ToShortDateString() as I suggested? You may need to use an explicit cast ((DateTime)rdr["DOB"]).ToShortDateString()

Comment: Hi Paul, I tried both of those and no luck unfortunately. It would work fine if it was a regular text box but it seems to be as soon as I add the "Type=Date" into the front code within the asp:TextBox it just overwrites the value with "dd/mm/yyyy" - Thanks btw

Comment: My misunderstanding - I thought you did not want the time - try setting the type to DateTimeLocal : see final answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22441830/using-textbox-with-type-datetime-in-asp-net

Comment: Sorry Paul, I don't think I explained very well what's happening. Basically the textbox is not populating with my date from the database. I don't want the time to display, but it is just the issue where nothing is populating in that text box but if I didn't use the type=date on the front code it populates fine. Its just as soon as I bring in that calendar type it doesn't pull the proper date down

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dbo.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(rdr["dob"]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```